# Login trouble with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Hello I'm trying to enter Username into text box and press the button Submit to login to the page but the page just refreshes. What am i doing wrong?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

username = input("Enter in your username: ")

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Dev\\WebDrivers\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://secure.runescape.com/m=accountappeal/passwordrecovery")

username_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
username_textbox.send_keys(username)

recover_button = driver.find_element_by_id("passwordRecovery")
recover_button.submit()
```

Comment: I think you want `recover_button.click()`, not `recover_button.submit()`.

Comment: Lol that helped! Wow that was easy! thanks!